# Matching partial data in rows to data in column and populate date of matched values in another row in Excel

Tags: excel

1. In worksheet 'A' I have row 1 for college names.  College ID is
   concatenated with the college name, after a space, within parentheses.
        Sheet 1 (A1:E1):

   ```
   "Wyndall college (123)", "Jeffersone college (99)", "Lyndale College (45)", "Lincoln college (60)", "Salt Lake College (40)"
   ```
2. In worksheet 'B', I have column A for college names (no college ID
   concatenated) and column B for number of students. Sheet 2 (A1:A4):

   ```
   "wyndall college"   100
   "Gates College"     300
   "Jefferson College"  50
   "Lincoln college"   150
   ```
3. Worksheet B many not have all college names that exist in worksheet
   A and vice versa!
4. I want to populate row 2 (A2:E2) in worksheet A with the number of students
   from worksheet 'B' if the college name matches (even partial) in the
   two worksheets.
5. How do I do that thru Excel formula and functions?

Answer (score 0):

For example:

[image]

After parsing with Text To Columns. On a larger scale [Fuzzy Lookup](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011) might be more suitable.

Comment: thats not the scenario. Instead, College names in sheet1 are in the 1st row. not in the columns. i mentioned that in my question. Let me know if there is information missing from my question to fully understand the scenario.

Comment: Tried HLOOKUP, but it is giving me #NA.

Comment: No buddy! can't transpose the rows to columns or vice versa. Problem is that that's the way spread sheet should look like.  There is no College ID in the sheet 2.  We gotta match names only.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by a "partial match".  If you can match up to the ID number, and the ID number is always inside parentheses, then you can use something like:

```
B1: =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(TRIM(LEFT(A1,FIND("(",A1)-1)),B!$A$1:$B$4,2,FALSE),"")
```

and fill down.

If you only want to match the first word, then look for the first **space** in the Find function.  If you mean something else by a "partial match", you'll have to add detail.

Comment: By poartial match, I mean the value in row 1 (college names + college id) does not need to match with values (college names only) in column A of the sheet 2.  You can't match college id as it is not present in sheet B.  You gotta match college names.  The formula you presented is giving error.

Comment: The second formula I gave matches on the data you presented. Why don't you share the error you are seeing?

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood, you wrote you had college names in Sheet A Row 1, but then you wrote that the names were in A1:A5, which is what I assumed -- one name per cell.  Is it different?

Comment: If your college name (ID) strings really are in the first row (A1:E1) then, with the same formula in B1, instead of filling down, just fill to the right.